# if/else format within while loop

Tags: c++, block, if-statement, braces

```
while(true)
{ 
  cout << "Name: ";
  getline(cin, Name);
  if(Name == "Stop")
    break;

  cout << "Additional Name - Y/N: ";
  getline(cin, additional);
  if (additional == "Y") 
    cout << "Additional Name: ";
  getline(cin, Name2);
  else
    cout << "Location: ";
  getline(cin, Location);
  if(Location == "Stop")
    break;
}


chief.cpp: In member function ‘void BookList::Fill()’:
chief.cpp:128: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
```

After the user enters the first name, I would like to give the option to enter a second name.  If "N" just skip down to Location, if "Y" go to Name2 and then on to Location.

Comment: It would be useful if you'd indicated line 128 on the listing, although you did get useful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enclose the statements between the `if` and the `else` within brackets `{` ... `}`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add braces here:

```
if (additional == "Y") 
     cout << "Additional Name: ";
      getline(cin, Name2);
else
     cout << "Location: ";
     getline(cin, Location);
```

Try:

```
if (additional == "Y") 
{
     cout << "Additional Name: ";
     getline(cin, Name2);
}
// You could have an else here, but that would make location only happen if "additional" was not "Y"

 cout << "Location: ";
 getline(cin, Location);
```

I suspect that you always want the following lines (getting location) to occur, so in this case, no else is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the body of `if` in braces to get rid of the error. By the looks of it you also need to enclose the `else` body in braces:

```
if (additional == "Y") {
  cout << "Additional Name: ";
  getline(cin, Name2);
 } else {
  cout << "Location: ";
  getline(cin, Location);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may only discard the braces (`{` and `}`) around blocks when the block contains exactly one statement (something ending with a semicolon (`;`)) or another statement with a block (`if`, `for`,  `while`, etc).

For example, you can do this:

```
while (true)
    if (foo) {
        printf("Hello, ");
        printf("world\n");
    }
```

or even

```
while (true)
    if (foo)
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("Hello, ");
            printf("World!\n");
        }
```

But in your code, you need to use braces since your `if` statement contains two statements before the `else` statement. Therefore the `if` statement end after the `cout` line.

The end result should thus look something like this:

```
if (additional == "Y") {
   cout << "Additional Name: ";
   getline(cin, Name2);
}
else {
   cout << "Location: ";
   getline(cin, Location);
}
```